# Rails 4.2, render hardcoded html outside the controller, not as a template

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, render

I'm new on ror, have some sort of a beginner question

I want to render a html file which is being sent from a remote server
The file comes as a string representing the html file

```
``
<html>
<head>
<meta ... />
<script />
<style ... />
</head>

<body>
 content
</body>

</html>
``
```

My middleware will render this page when its triggered. the thing is that this html is a dynamic file which I cant store on the server as is

How can I render the html code above not as a template instead of the original page?

Comment: You question is not clear to me and it seems pretty broad. Is your question about how to load that file from the server, how to send it to the client, how to write and use a middleware or is your question about the issues that might happen in such a setup? Can you please elaborate and show the code you already have?

Comment: @spickermann, not loading a file/template presenting hardcoded HTML from a variable into a page
x = "<html>...</html>", render x into page